# SQL groupby by with count on specific column showing up as part of the results

Tags: sql, grouping

I have the following data

> **Maker** |  **CarName** | **Year**
>
> Toyota    |  Yaris   | 2017
>
> Renault   |  Clio   | 2017
>
> Renault   |  Twingo   | 2015

I am looking for a query that would return me this

> **Maker** |  **CarName** | **Year** | **MakerCount**
>
> Toyota    |  Yaris   | 2017 | 1
>
> Renault   |  Clio   | 2017 | 2
>
> Renault   |  Twingo   | 2015 | 2

However I can only have that count column if only showing the Maker column:

```
SELECT Maker, count(Maker) as MakerCount GROUP BY Maker
```

Any tip on how to solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join to a subquery which computes the counts:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.MakerCount
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Maker, COUNT(*) AS MakerCount
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Maker
) t2
    ON t1.Maker = t2.Maker;
```

This would make sense if you were using MySQL.  If you are using a database which supports analytic functions you can avoid the subquery:

```
SELECT t.*,
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Maker) MakerCount
FROM yourTable t;
```